# After tagging a service in services.yml symfony starts throwing ReflectionException

Tags: symfony

I have the following configuration in my SF2 Bundle

```
parameters:
    catalogue.title.class: My\SomeBundle\Services\TitleService

services:
    catalogue.title:
        class: %catalogue.title.class%
```

Which works like a charm.

Now I want to enhance the configured service and tag it so it gets the `knp_paginator` injected (I've also tried with other tags). My config becomes:

```
parameters:
    catalogue.title.class: My\SomeBundle\Services\TitleService

services:
    catalogue.title:
        class: %catalogue.title.class%
        tags: 
            - { name: knp_paginator.injectable, paginator: knp_paginator }
```

For the mentioned tag to work the service implements the `Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Definition\PaginatorAware`. As mentioned on the [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle#dependency-injection) docs.

Running my app will show the following:

`ReflectionException: Class %catalogue.title.class% does not exist`.

Since it works without adding the `tags` part, I know the class does exist.

Replacing `%catalogue.title.class%` with the value of the parameter (the fully qualified class name) solves the issue, but we are using this way of configuring our service classes in all our projects and really don't want to deviate from that just to resolve this issue.

[EDIT] Using a different parameter like `catalogue_title_class` or `my_abc` has the same result.

I'm running Symfony version 2.3.5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using Reflection anywhere in your dependency injection for that service?

Comment: I'm not, but the KnpPaginatorBundle Compiler pass is. It's reflecting my definition class to check for a specific interface implementation. Which is where the exception is coming from. Thanks @Flosculus. I now know why it doesn't work!

Comment: After @Flosculus pointed my in the right direction I did some digging on the KnpPaginatorBundle issues list and found [issues/207](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/207) which is exactly what I ran into. Hopefully it gets merged soon.

Answer (score -2):

Probably this exceptions throws because of same names of class of parameter and provided service name.

Try to rename

```
parameters:
catalogue.title.class: My\SomeBundle\Services\TitleService
```

to some other name

```
parameters:
catalogue_title.class: My\SomeBundle\Services\TitleService
```

and use this

```
services:
catalogue.title:
    class: %catalogue_title.class%
    tags: 
        - { name: knp_paginator.injectable, paginator: knp_paginator }
```

Comment: That doesn't have any effect. I can change the parameter to whatever, the result is still the same.